# permissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/Program Files/colorat/data.txt'

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe

I made an app using PyQt5 and put two files in it (image and text)
And I put the path to the program files(c:/program files)
because I want to put the whole files in c:/Program Files/colorat
I made an installer for my app using inno setup and it puts all the files in the program files

but when I install the app it doesn't work and then I found out that this is happening because my app can't access the files because it needs administrator permission because it's in program files
and when I run the python script it gives me this error:

```
permissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:/Program Files/colorat/data.txt'
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: You need to run application with administrator privileges (`Run as administrator`) to be able change files inside program files

Comment: yes I know, when I run the app as administrator it works, but I want it to work without running it as administrator

Comment: Not sure if that is a good practice to save data and log files inside Program Files, but if you want to do that you need to change permissions of colorat folder manually https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3dd0d2f9-5b2f-46df-950f-36887c98369c/give-full-permission-for-the-users-in-program-files-folder?forum=w7itprogeneral . Or change permissions by some initial separated script running as admin once after installation is complete. In this case I recommend to create some subfolder colorat/data only for data and change permissions for subfolder only